# cytoscape : how to disable node and edge selection?

Tags: cytoscape.js

How can I disable some nodes/edges in a cytoscape.js graph to be selected? the 'unselectable: true' option doesn't work. Can anyone link a working example?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent the user from grabbing or moving a node or lock the nodes position:

If you want to lock the node, use this:
[nodes.lock()](http://js.cytoscape.org/#nodes.lock)

If you want to make the node ungrabbable, use this:
[nodes.ungrabify()](http://js.cytoscape.org/#nodes.ungrabify)

If your goal is to make the nodes not selectable, you can always use the function provided by Cytoscape:

Enable:

```
cy.autounselectify( true );
```

Disable:

```
cy.autounselectify( false );
```

I really can't find anything about `unselectable: true`, did you confuse it with the `:unselectable` state from [here](http://js.cytoscape.org/#selectors/state)?

Comment: Don't know if that's the OP use case, but here's mine: I want to disable click-to-select because I want to use the click event for (and only for) a different purpose. but I do want to leave the nodes selectable and movable via multi-select (i.e. area selection)

Comment: You can [bind](https://js.cytoscape.org/#cy.on) the `click` event on nodes and call [`event.target.unselect()`](https://js.cytoscape.org/#eles.unselect) it in there. Is that possible in your use case?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't want to make any assumptions about whether it is already selected or not, I wanted the click to just leave it the way it was. what I end up doing is making it temporarily `unselectify()` in my click handler, and releasing it with `selectify()` after half a second, ugly but works :)